# LaunchScreen Issues in Xcode

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, launch-screen

I am trying to design the Launch screen in XCode but facing one issue where I can't get any hint of how to resolve it. I am trying to build Xcode launch screen project but keep getting below error whenever I edit any of the LaunchScreen from Visual Studio.

**Xamarin/Xamarin.h' file not found**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved, the issue was with image dimensions. Seems to be a bug where if you have image with too big dimensions it will cause your splash screen to go black. No build required on XCode side, when you update anything on story board it get reflect in VS project. So just want to share my experience if anyone face the same issue.